# Hibernate/c3pO doesn't work under Tomcat - Windows 10: apparent deadlock

Tags: windows, eclipse, hibernate, tomcat, c3p0

My app uses Hibernate and c3po, and isn't starting under windows 10 + eclipse Oxygen + Tomcat 8, while under Linux works fine with the same configuration.

These are some lines the console shows when starting Tomcat

```
2017/11/27 18:21:03 WARN  com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner  - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@15cc07ce -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
```

This should a connection problem as reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730844/c3p0-apparent-deadlock-when-the-threads-are-all-empty) .

This seems confirmed by an exception I get:

```
2017/11/27 18:21:14 WARN  com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@1e723184 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATALE: the remaining connection slots are reserveed to non replica superusers connections
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.readStartupMessages(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:469)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:112)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
```

From postgresql log I see there are many connection until the db says it cannot allocate more. The connections are far above 10, while I have this in my `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">3</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
```

`psql -h localhost -U user db` works fine

I used [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and [RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap) under Windows to capture the connections and it seems the connections are acquired, as the log says, but after seeing Postgres saying "ready for queries", they are closed, if I saw well.

What else can I look at to debug what's happening??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that I was using the wrong postgresql driver. I have java 8, and using [PostgreSQL JDBC 4.2 Driver, 42.1.4](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.1.4.jar) solved the issue.