# War taking too much time to deploy on Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat7, deadlock, c3p0

I am currently using Tomcat7(localhost) as web server and Java 8.
My application is not that big to take hours to upload but it goes on when trying uploading the war.And at the end it failed deploying war.
I have checked the logs and as per my understanding somewhere deadlock is happening but unable to figure it out the root cause, ***any help will be much appreciated.***

Here are logs-->

```
    INFO: Registering annotated classes: [class com.stupefy.config.DBConfig]
Aug 05, 2020 12:03:49 AM com.mchange.v2.log.MLog
INFO: MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
Aug 05, 2020 12:03:49 AM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry
INFO: Initializing c3p0-0.9.5.2 [built 08-December-2015 22:06:04 -0800; debug? true; trace: 10]
Aug 05, 2020 12:03:49 AM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource
INFO: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@3e99dc89 [ connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@fc35200c [ acquireIncrement -> 1, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceSynchronousCheckins -> false, identityToken -> 1hge13eab1ftejmdxnjxi7|13d7fcbe, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 5, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 1800, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 20, maxStatements -> 150, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 5, nestedDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@b1fac6b6 [ description -> null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken -> 1hge13eab1ftejmdxnjxi7|116eb718, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://cosmoverse-db.cyee2rqmhok9.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/stupefy?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false, properties -> {password=******, handling_mode=DELAYED_ACQUISITION_AND_HOLD, user=******} ], preferredTestQuery -> null, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false; userOverrides: {} ], dataSourceName -> null, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 1hge13eab1ftejmdxnjxi7|6bd6cb72, numHelperThreads -> 3 ]
Aug 05, 2020 12:04:09 AM com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner
WARNING: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@66019c0d -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
Aug 05, 2020 12:04:09 AM com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner
```

```
            Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge13eab1ftejmdxnjxi7|6bd6cb72]-HelperThread-#0,5,main]
                java.base@13.0.2/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
                java.base@13.0.2/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:493)
                java.base@13.0.2/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:482)
                java.base@13.0.2/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
                java.base@13.0.2/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:339)
                java.base@13.0.2/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:603)
                com.mysql.cj.core.io.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:202)
                com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaSocketConnection.connect(MysqlaSocketConnection.java:57)
                com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.connect(MysqlaSession.java:122)
                com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:1619)
                com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1601)
                com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:633)
                com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:347)
                com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:219)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
                com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
                com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
                com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
```

```
    
Aug 05, 2020 12:05:09 AM com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner
WARNING: Task com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@18184915 (in deadlocked PoolThread) failed to complete in maximum time 60000ms. Trying interrupt().
```

Comment: The Deadlock is the warning. some other thing is causing this problem

Comment: @tusharwason but logs are saying this only and no war deployed :(

Comment: Please check this if it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730844/c3p0-apparent-deadlock-when-the-threads-are-all-empty

Comment: @tusharwason  just checked i have used those 2 max values already